# javascript(maybe also Ajax) not working after migrating from asp.net 3.5 windows 2003 to asp.net 4.0 windows 2008

Tags: asp.net, windows, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET web form application that now needs to be moved to a windows 2008 server.

The current version uses asp.net 3.5. On the new server(windows 2008), some javascripts do not seem to work. The controls in the page are wrapped around and updatepanel. When i press Ok, after selecting a radio button initiated on a gridview column  as shown below.

```
private void InitCheckBoxes(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{


Literal output = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("RadioButtonMarkup");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<input type=");
sb.Append(@"");
sb.Append("radio");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("name=");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("SYearGroup");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("id=");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("RowSelector{0}");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("value=");
sb.Append(@" ");
sb.Append("{0}");
sb.Append(@" ");
output.Text = string.Format(sb.ToString(), e.Row.RowIndex);

if (SYearGroupIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
{
output.Text += @" checked=" + @"checked""";
output.Text += @"/>";


}


}
}
```

The actual grid has the following markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gview_sy"  width="1000px"
     EmptyDataText="No Stock and year was found for the selected year." 
     DataSourceID="obj_sy" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     DataKeyNames="AId,s_CodeId" 
     runat="server"  AllowSorting="false" OnRowCommand="gview_sy_RowCommand" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="gview_sy_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     OnSorted="gview_sy_Sorted" onsorting="gview_sy_Sorting"       
     OnRowCreated="gview_sy_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="RadioButtonMarkup" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" ShowHeader="true"
             SortExpression="Year" HeaderText="WorkingYear" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:button id="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="64px"     Visible="True"
     OnClick="btnOK_Click"></asp:button>
```

When I press Ok after a selection, things work both on my development laptop (vista SP2) and my current server windows 2008 asp.net 3.5.  But nothing happens on the new server.

Can anyone tell how to go about finding the problem?

Many thanks in advance
Mike